# Install Python on Self Hosted Windows runner for Github Action

Tags: python, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I am using Windows Server 2019 as a self hosted runner for my Github Actions. I need to install Python.
Shall install this python as one time activity or through github action workflow every time that workflow is executed?

I came across [this](https://github.com/actions/setup-python/blob/main/docs/advanced-usage.md#windows) but this is confusing. Do I need to install using MSI installer? Also need to update PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with any runner, you need to have everything set up to be able to use it.

> Do I need to install using MSI installer? Also need to update PATH.

Yes.

Comment: so if I download python from its release page and install manually, that will do?

Comment: That should be okay, .msi installer will install Python, it should also update PATH in env.variables but it is worth to check it.

Comment: You can also use miniconda for virtual environment and set Path manually yourself. It actually same process which .msi installer does it.

Note that if you use Python .msi installer and you set PATH variable (installer do it for you) you will never be able to use virtual environments.

You should set some requirements for yourself and decide which way is the best. In-system Python? Or virtual environment with set location.

If you decide on virtual you cannot execute python as "python" in CLI but "D:\loc..\python.exe".

There are multiple ways to setup this. Depends on your needs.